# Method for identifying surges in multi-year inbound 911 call data

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have a dataset which consists of calls placed to 911 occurring over a period of 13 years. The annual total calls has increased significantly over time, starting at around 200000 per year, and then increasing to at least 500000 after the first 3 years. The total for the most recent 5 year period is closer to 700000 annually.

The data consists of a unique event identifier and a time stamp - as well as other details.

My goal is to identify “surges” of calls occurring within several separate fixed time periods: 1 minute, 2 minutes, 5 minutes and 10 minutes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A potential method is performing [change point detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_detection). However, within the field of change point detection, there exists a wide variety of techniques applicable to particular problem statements.

In your case, it seems you would like to perform a "sliding fixed window" (1, 2, 5, 10 minute) change point. A very basic algorithm would be to compute an aggregate statistic (max, min, average number of calls) for each time window. More advanced algorithms detect a shift in the mean or variance for a time window. Which, in your case, should be detected by a change in mean over longer time period windows such as year(s).

If you use Python, the following [Ruptures package](https://centre-borelli.github.io/ruptures-docs/) offers some of the more advanced change point detection methods.